# Using Different Host than Registrar for Subdomain

Tags: subdomain, domain-registrar

I purchased a domain through Moniker: mysamplewebsite.com.

I would like to have it hosted through freehosting.com.

I would like to have a subdomain (sub.mysamplewebsite.com) point to my synology NAS (mynas.synology.me).

**Moniker Dashboard**

Status: Registered

Expiration Date: 01/15/2019

Nameserver: ns1.freehosting.com, ns2.freehosting.com

*DNS settings for mysamplewebsite.com:*

Web settings

Redirect: Not Set

Link with IP (A/AAAA Record): Nothing Set

Mail Settings

None Set

TXT-Record

Blank

SRV
None Set

NAPTR
None Set

CAA
None Set

TTL
300 sec (Previously 28800 sec)

Nothing set for the following:

Own Nameservers (Glue Records)

DynamicDNS

**WARNINGS**: "Currently you are not using our Nameservers. Please note that changes in your DNS zone can only be made when our nameservers are used. Click on "Whois/Nameservers" and select "Standard Nameservers" to use our Nameservers. Configure Nameservers"
**/Moniker Dashboard**

So, based on the warning, does that mean that if i choose to host my website through freehosting.com, I can not use moniker to point my subdomain to my synology NAS? If so, it looks like I'd have to pay a one time fee for a subdomain through freehosting.com.

I can't get sub.mysamplewebsite.com to work from my phone, home computer, or friend's computer (on different ISP).

mysamplewebsite.com works from my phone, but not my home computer, and not from my friend's computer -- so I'm thinking it's a DNS issues that is still in progress?

From the Moniker dashboard do I need to change the DNS settings for mysamplewebsite.com so that it's Linked with an IP (A/AAAA record) or is just using their nameservers good enough? I can't seem to find an IP address from freehosting.com to use.

Really, if anyone has a good YouTube tutorial video that can help a newbie through this process I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

At your registrar you need to give your DNS hosting company nameserver NS records.

At your DNS hosting company you will need to edit the zone served by their nameservers and add an `A` record for your subdomain poiting to the IP used by your NAS.

Some registrars can also provide nameservers for you and let you edit the zone.
Thus you will need to find which provider gives you the feature (editing the zone contents) you need.

PS: people would be better able to help you if you gave the true names involved without obfuscation. And if you need to give names for documentation use the standard appropriate ones, that is `example.com` `example.net` and `example.org`. Do not invent other names.